# Get memory usage as reported by windows 8 task manager

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

How do I get the total memory used by my C# application?
I have tried:
GC.GetTotalMemory()
Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize, PrivateMemorySize64,
VirtualMemorySize, VMS64, PagedMS.

They do report various values, which is OK. But these values differ from what I see in the Task Manager.

I am using Windows 8 and the task manager shows resources used by all apps separately on the right hand side besides the application name. 
My Application's current memory is also displayed. Suppose it is 18.9 MB, and drops down to say ~9 MB if I force a GC.Collect().

Now,
before GC.Collect():
PrivateMemorySize & PMS64 both report ~42 (after converting to MB)
and GetTotalMemory() gives ~3
PagedMS & PagedMS64 gives ~379

and after GC.Collect():
PrivateMemorySize & PMS64 both report ~39 (after converting to MB)
and GetTotalMemory() gives ~1
PagedMS & PagedMS64 gives ~367

But these are different from task manager's display. What I want to get is the '18.9' and '9' ie. the memory usage of my application as reported by the windows 8 task manager.
How do I do this through code behind?
I use .Net 4.0, visual studio 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd not try to replicate what taskmgr does but use the number that logically makes sense for you. Probably, that's private bytes (of course, use the 64 bit version). Private bytes are those bytes that are actually in use and that are not shared with any other process.

There is no memory number that is perfect (neither on Windows nor on Linux) because memory usage is open to interpretation as soon as multiple processes share some pages.

Private bytes is very appropriate for most apps, though.

**Update: The Windows 8 Task Manager shows Working Set Private Bytes.** This is an awful metric to use. It tells you how much memory of this app is currently in RAM. This can be much less than actual memory usage. It does *not* tell you how much memory will be freed if this process exits.

Comment: thanks. What I was trying to check was if my app used up too much memory and free it accordingly. But as I said, the code in my App seems to give me almost twice the value shown by win 8 TM. But the total values in the TM seems to correspond to those displayed by another independent RAM Defragment/Cleanup software. Thus, it seems more likely that the TM and the other RAM softwares are more correct. So, I wanted to see if I could get similar readings as those shown by win 8 TM.

Comment: I found the number that Task Manager 8 uses. Don't use it - I explained why in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to use it, But as per your reasoning, I will not rely solely on this property.
Any suggestions on what to pair this with? The thing is, I need to display the memory usage, but the user is pretty weird guy. Even though I can explain this, he will compare it with TM ans say that the values I display are not proper. So, I can use this for display, while I can rely on other things to actually trigger clean-up.

Comment: I understand, this reasoning makes sense. Show him the TM value and use private bytes as you control private bytes. Yo do not control anything WS related.